# Not able to find onclick method assigned to ImageView

Tags: android

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MissedCallServices"
    >
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#ffff00"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/home"
            android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:onClick="gotoHome"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:enabled="true"
            />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The code snippet above is the layout of my activity in 2nd ImageView. I have given onClick="gotoHome" but I am getting no such method exception.
I don't know why I am getting such exception . This is running properly in emulator

Added from reply:

```
package com.example.tanayyawalkar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
public class MissedCallServices extends Activity 
{
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_missed_call_services);
    }

    public void gotoHome(View v) 
    {
        try
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            // do something on back.
            return;
         }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.v("Error",e.getMessage());
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: add java code also

Comment: Where is your gotoHome function?

Comment: It is in my java file

Comment: Please submit your java code as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it is happening because of `android:theme` attribute of your Toolbar,Your onClick gets the wrong Context `(android.support.v7.internal.view.ContextThemeWrapper is not your Activity)`. Try implementing listeners in code, don't use through xml. Remove `theme` attribute and use `style` instead

Lets say imageview has `id` `home`

```
ImageButton homeButton = (ImageButton ) findViewById(R.id.yourbuttonid)
homeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 //here comes the code
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
            }
});
```

Comment: Do I need to write this code in onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) I am new to android

Comment: Yes just copy it and paste it into ```onCreate``` but don't forget to add id to ```ImageButton``` and same id into ```R.id.thatIdYouJustAddedIntoImageButton```

Comment: I am using ImageView so I will use ImageView right?

Comment: Exactly You would have to use ImageView in your case.